# How to create a "Questionnaire" like form in CRM 2011 Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm creating my first Silverlight app for CRM 2011 and while i've been able to load data in from a couple of different entities, i'm not sure on the best way to display the data as I need it.

The entities are individual parts of what is essentially a questionnaire, so i have the section, questions and responses and I would like to have them laid out like

section 1

question 1 answer 1

question 2 answer 2

...

NEW PAGE (using pager control)

Section 2

question 1 answer 1

and so on.

There isn't a set amount of sections or questions, but each question will only have one answer to it.

Can someone point me in the right direction on the best control to use for this, as right now I can't immediately see the best option.

Thanks

Comment: These two resources will help to achieve what you're set out to do:
[Crm 2011 Survey Creator - a solution](http://lucianodangelo.blogspot.com/2012/03/crm-2011-survey-creator-beta.html)
[Creating Rich Data Forms in Silverlight](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Creating-Rich-Data-Forms-in-Silverlight-3-Introduction.aspx)

Comment: The data forms look perfect for what i want, but I can't find them as a control in visual studio. Does it need to be installed in separately or should it come with all the other standard controls?

Comment: Nevermind, i've found it now. Turns out i didnt have the toolkit installed but now i've done that it has appeared. Thanks for your help.